# Grails AbstractService cannot inject another service

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

I am trying to create Grails app with the following service architecture:

```
abstract class CrawlerService{
   def databaseService
   ...
}

class SpecificCrawlerService extends CrawlerService{...}

class AnotherCrawlerService extends CrawlerService{...}

class DatabaseService{...}
```

I want to use databaseService object in  both non-abstract classes but the service is always null. Has anyone faced such issue?

Comment: I have not faced that issue, but I'm curious... Why the abstract class? What is it that you want to inherit? You may be able to use a trait, or composition instead.

Comment: That was my first thought to share common functionality of different services (in this case each service initializes http connection to some webservice - this is common) then each service processing is different. I wanted to have contract which enforces on child services implementation of some abstract  methods.

Comment: How about creating a Grails service (or even just a bean) which initializes the http connection to the webservice, and have it expose some methods? Then, *inject* that service into the services who need it. To enforce the implementation of some methods, you can use an interface.

Comment: This is one solution which seems to be clean. Thanks for that. I still don't feel the Grails approach to certain problems.